# How does an OS and control unit interact?

Tags: windows, operating-system, cpu, interaction

An operating system (OS) manages how a software should act when a key is pressed, what software to send to the control unit to get processed (what software to run), it controls the output devices such as the monitor etc etc. Basically bridges the gap between a software and a hardware. I can tell how it's a program.

The OS runs on the cpu. If this is true, then surely the control unit must process the operating system all the time which would leave no room for other instructions to be executed. Also, if the operating system gives the control unit instructions (on what to run) and manages how a key press should be interpreted by that software, how does the OS do it? On what does the OS run on? The CPU or the RAM? Surely it doesn't run on the RAM because RAM is a storage unit which cannot run a software?

So say I press the key "A" on my keyboard. The keyboard sends an instrcution which gets to the control unit. The control unit processes it and sends the information (that the key 'A' is pressed) to the GPU. The GPU then does it's thing and the key press is displayed on my notepad. What is the role of an OS in this scenario?

Also please correct me because I feel like the above paragraph is wrong. What happens when you press a key on the keyboard? What path does the instrcution take? (path meaning to the cu/os etc)

It would help if you could explain it in simple terms as i am just beginning to learn about the OS and CU and I don't really know about a software in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

> An operating system (OS) manages how a software should act when a key is pressed, what software to send to the control unit to get processed (what software to run), it controls the output devices such as the monitor etc etc. Basically bridges the gap between a software and a hardware. I can tell how it's a program.

There exists several CPU architectures like x86-64, RISC-V, ARM. ARM and x86-64 are the most widespread today. You will certainly find an ARM CPU architecture in a phone while in desktop computers you will find an x86-64. This is mostly due to power efficiency and market shares and other stuff like that.

Today, CPUs contain several billions of transistors and they are more complex than a control unit with a data bus and an address bus. You can still use this view of the CPU to understand the simple principle behind but it is overly simplified.

In this answer, I'll take **x86-64** CPU architecture as an example because I am more aware of how it works.

In general, there is a manual which comes with the brand of CPU you have. For example, Intel has the Developers Manuals which comprises 4 volumes (download here: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4.html). Most CPU manufacturers follow a specific architecture for their CPU. For example, AMD and Intel follow the x86 architecture which has been extended to x86-64 (64 bits). And ARM Ltd. has ARM which is licensed to other companies for manufacturing (Qualcomm, etc).

The Developers Manuals are quite long but they are a reference to guide you to understand how to use the processor on the software level. In them, there is a distinction between what is software and hardware.

In particular, there is the way that instructions need to be encoded to be recognized by hardware. This is called the instruction set. For example, a very simple instruction is `hlt` in assembly. It is encoded as `F4` in hexadecimal or `1111 0100` in binary. This instruction will make the processor halt and wait for an interrupt.  In x86-64, there is a lot of instructions and the instruction set is often extended. This is why computers with x86 CPUs are called CISC (Complex instruction set computers). In the meantime, computers with ARM processors are RISC (reduced instruction set).

The way that the memory is accessed depends on the type of memory. Today you will have mostly DDR DRAM for main memory and SRAM for registers. DDR DRAM stands for Double Data Rate Dynamic Random Access Memory. The DDR DRAM is a JEDEC standard. You can find the standards on internet on the JEDEC website (https://www.jedec.org). Some are not free while some are free to access. DRAM manufacturers use these standards to manufacture DIMMs which contain DRAM chips. The DIMM is the actual green board that you plug into your motherboard for adding or removing main memory. DRAM is mostly an array of capacitors containing a charge or not and a MOSFET transistor controlling the flow of the charge. You could think of it like if the charge moves from the capacitor to the SRAM cells of the registers on the bus lines. Then the CPU does operations on them and then charges back some other capacitors with an answer. In reality, it is more complex.

> The OS runs on the cpu. If this is true, then surely the control unit must process the operating system all the time which would leave no room for other instructions to be executed. Also, if the operating system gives the control unit instructions (on what to run) and manages how a key press should be interpreted by that software, how does the OS do it? On what does the OS run on? The CPU or the RAM? Surely it doesn't run on the RAM because RAM is a storage unit which cannot run a software?

The OS does run on the CPU but only at certain points in time. What you are missing is interrupts here to understand how it works. There is an IDTR special register in the processor. The IDTR register stores the position of the IDT in RAM. The IDT tells the processor where to go (at what address to jump to) when a certain interrupt happens. Also, there exists several exceptions caught by x86-64 processors (https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions). When the exception cause happens, the processor looks in the IDT and jumps to the handler (the address) specified in the IDT.

Basically, OSes today are mostly interrupt driven. They don't "run" in itself. They run when an interrupt happens, do something, then leave room for other processes. There exists timers on motherboards and in processors today. These timers are mostly made with crystal oscillators which oscillate at specific frequencies. If you know the frequency, then after a certain amount of oscillations, a certain amount of time has passed. The OS can thus program these timers at boot to trigger an interrupt after a certain time. OSes thus program the timer and leave room for user mode processes. When the timer interrupt happens, the OS will determine by an algorithm (like round-robin, perfectly fair, etc.) what process will next have CPU time. This process will run for a certain time, etc.

> So say I press the key "A" on my keyboard. The keyboard sends an instrcution which gets to the control unit. The control unit processes it and sends the information (that the key 'A' is pressed) to the GPU. The GPU then does it's thing and the key press is displayed on my notepad. What is the role of an OS in this scenario?

I'll link to an answer which clearly points out how the keyboard works on modern computers: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141870/when-are-a-controllers-registers-loaded-and-ready-to-inform-an-i-o-operation/141918#141918

Basically, the keyboard doesn't send an instruction to the CPU. The keyboard will be polled by the xHC and, when the xHC writes the result in RAM, it will trigger an interrupt. The OS will then look in RAM for the result and, if it detects any change, it will send a message to the application which currently has focus stating that a key was pressed. The application is often free to even ignore the keypress.

Also, you are right that GPUs control the screen today but it is rather complex. Today, all peripherals (including integrated GPUs, the xHC etc.) are PCI devices. These devices are interacted with using memory mapped registers (mapped in RAM). You write to RAM and it writes to registers of these devices. This way, you can control the devices. GPUs are very complex and, often, their drivers are closed source. The OS thus needs a modular driver model which supports adding third party drivers to it. For example, Linux allows to load a third party driver to it as modules. These modules have read, write, open and ioctl functions. The ioctl (IO control) function behave as a general interface between user mode and kernel mode because it has a request argument and a variable amount of arguments after. GPU manufacturers also have to provide full fledged user mode libraries to interact with the driver from user mode. Otherwise, if you don't know how the driver works, how do you use it? Basically, the GPU manufacturer provides an OpenGL implementation in the form of a big library. This library is linked against in the compilation command and the functions of OpenGL you call are defined in this library. For example, on Linux the X Server has an OpenGL extension. When a graphics card (without framebuffer driver) is used, the X Server will start using OpenGL to draw the windows on the screen. It will make calls in the manufacturer provided library to draw onto the screen. This library will basically do ioctl, read and write calls on a file (virtual filesystem). The OS will simply provide a generic file that the library will make operations on to interact with the graphics card. The underneath driver (the module) can do very complex things and call all global kernel functions.